# Is the supremum of a sequence of random variables a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, supremum-and-infimum

In the book *A probability path*, a random variable is defined as a function from a probability space to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ the usual borel algebra over the reals. In Proposition 3.2.6. they seem to claim that the supremum of any sequence of random variables is itself a random variable, which seems incorrect to me:

Take $X_n$ to be random variables following dirac distribution at $n$, that is $X_n = n$ is a constant function. Then there is no supremum over $\mathbb{R}$! Did they forget to require boundedness or am i missing something? Here are screenshots for reference:

[image]
At first i thought maybe they meant only for finitely many, but then they apply (i) for countably many...

[image]

Comment: It looks like they indeed forgot to require boundedness, or else they are really considering "extended" random variables that are allowed to be $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: @Michael Thought of that possibility too, but no, they aren't.